# Why is "{{.Release.namespace}}" rendered empty?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I understand that `{{.Release.namespace}}` will render the namespace where the application being installed by `helm`. In that case, `helm template` command will render it as empty string (since it doesn't know yet the release namespace).

However, what makes me surprise is `helm upgrade --install` command (i haven't tried other command such as `helm install`) also renders it empty on some cases.

Here is the example of my helm chart template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.app.name}}-{{.Values.app.track}}-internal
  namespace: {{.Release.namespace}}
  annotations:
    testAnnotate: "{{.Release.namespace}}"
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: {{.Values.app.name}}
    environment: {{.Values.app.env}}
    track: {{.Values.app.track}}
  type: ClusterIP
```

After invoke `helm upgrade --install` on that chart template (and installed it successfully), I then try to see the output of my resource

```
> kubectl get -o yaml svc java-maven-app-stable-internal -n data-devops
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    testAnnotate: ""
  creationTimestamp: 2018-08-09T06:56:41Z
  name: java-maven-app-stable-internal
  namespace: data-devops
  resourceVersion: "62906341"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/data-devops/services/java-maven-app-stable-internal
  uid: 5e888e6a-9ba1-11e8-912b-42010a9400fa
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.32.76.208
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: java-maven-app
    environment: stg
    track: stable
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

As you can see, I put `{{.Release.namespace}}` on 2 places:

- in `metadata.namespace` field
- in `metadata.annotations.testAnnotate` field.

But it only renders the correct namespace on `metadata.namespace` field. Any idea why?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The generated value `.Release.Namespace` is case-sensitive. The letter N in "namespace" should be capitalized.